# how do parallax mouse move effect pure javascript

Tags: javascript, css, parallax

How can I realize a parallax effect like [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/X7UwG/2/):

but **without** using `jQuery`, with pure javascript and only with an image?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#landing-content').mousemove(function(e){
    var x = -(e.pageX + this.offsetLeft) / 20;
    var y = -(e.pageY + this.offsetTop) / 20;
    $(this).css('background-position', x + 'px ' + y + 'px');
  });    
});
```

```css
#landing-content {
 overflow: hidden;
 background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/F2FPRMd.jpg);
 width: 100%;
 background-size: 150% 150%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 max-height: 500px;
 border-bottom: solid;
 border-bottom-color: #628027;
 border-bottom-width: 5px;
}

.slider {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 200px;
  max-width: 1002px;
}

.slider img {
 width: 80%;
 padding-left: 10%;
 padding-right: 10%;
 height: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="landing-content">
    <section class="slider"> 
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/fVWomWz.png"/>
            
    </section>
</div>
```

Note: like in the example, the element should move smoothly in the mouse direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could update two custom properties depending on the `clientX/clientY` coordinate which control the position of a background, like in this proof of concept

> [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EzjXZW)

---

```js
let dde = document.documentElement;
dde.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
  let ow = dde.offsetWidth; 
  let oh = dde.offsetHeight; 
  dde.style.setProperty('--mouseX', e.clientX * 100 / ow + "%");
  dde.style.setProperty('--mouseY', e.clientY * 100 / oh + "%");
});
```

```css
:root {
  --mouseX: 50%;
  --mouseY: 50%;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  inline-size: 100%;
  min-block-size: 100dvh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-size: auto 250%;
  background-position: var(--mouseX) var(--mouseY);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url('https://www.thesprucepets.com/thmb/uQnGtOt9VQiML2oG2YzAmPErrHo=/5441x0/filters:no_upscale():strip_icc()/all-about-tabby-cats-552489-hero-a23a9118af8c477b914a0a1570d4f787.jpg');
}
```

```html
<body></body>
```

In this example I've used an image covering the full viewport in height but really large. At the initial state the background is centered.

In JS on `mousemove` event you get the coordinate of the mouse (eg. `clientX` or `clientY`) and set a CSS custom property (`--mouseX/--mouseY`) with that value, which is used for background positioning.

Comment: Nope, correct one. I'm just saying that, if you're going to post an answer to an off-topic question (one which only has a link to code rather than the code being in the question), you could at least edit the question to be on-topic (by copying the code from the fiddle to the question here on SO). Or you risk having the question closed and deleted, since it is still off-topic.

Comment: @HereticMonkey thanks for the suggestion. I've edited the question, feel free to improve it if you like.

Comment: The Codepen example is very helpful! But it uses an old image link that no longer works, so it appears broken at first. Would it be possible to update the example image?

Comment: @D.Hammaker snippet updated.

Answer (score 1):

I've just 'translated' the jQuery code directly to normal JS

```js
//Call in document load event
document.getElementById("landing-content")
.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  var x = -(e.pageX + this.offsetLeft) / 20;
  var y = -(e.pageY + this.offsetTop) / 20;
  e.currentTarget.style.backgroundPosition = x + 'px ' + y + 'px';
})
```

```css
#landing-content {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/F2FPRMd.jpg);
  width: 100%;
  background-size: 150% 150%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  max-height: 500px;
  border-bottom: solid;
  border-bottom-color: #628027;
  border-bottom-width: 5px;
}

.slider {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 200px;
  max-width: 1002px;
}

.slider img {
  width: 80%;
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-right: 10%;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="landing-content">
  <section class="slider"> 
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/fVWomWz.png">
  </section>
</div>
```